# Can I setup an smtp server with Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: smtp

I want to run an smtp server that will distribute email alerts from various servers.

Comment: This is a very general question.  Have you tried Googling it?  Have you attempted to install any SMTP server software?   Where exactly are you running into problems?

Comment: @Mike I think that your question has been asked previously ([duplicated](http://askubuntu.com/faq#close)): [Setup a local testing SMTP server](http://askubuntu.com/q/4118/62483) - Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I setup an smtp server with Ubuntu Desktop?

The short answer is YES.

The longer answer is probably rooted in why you would choose Desktop versus Server. I'm guessing you want the GUI out of the box for ease of administration. For that (and other information on Servers in general and Desktops vs Servers), see [Frequently Asked Questions about the Ubuntu Server Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq).

Unfortunately, nothing will save you from the (exim|postfix|sendmail|webmail|doevcot|courrier|spamassassn|clam) configuration and administration. See [Setting up an Ubuntu System as an Email Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer) for details.